# Removing some elements from a list which satisfy some condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list with some file names(locations), what I am trying to do is I want to remove every elements from the list locations.

Condition: do not print the file name if it starts with the any of the strings in the excludes list.

```
locations = ['/data/mybackup/data/fil1',
            '/data/mybackup/data/fil2', 
            '/data/mybackup/data/fil3', 
            '/data/mybackup/song/fil1', 
            '/data/mybackup/song/fil2',
            '/data/mybackup/song/fil3', 
            '/data/archive/song/fil1', 
            '/data/archive/song/fil2', 
            '/data/archive/song/fil3', 
            '/data/archive/data/fil1', 
            '/local/archive/data/fil2', 
            '/local/archive/data/fil3',
            '/ebboks/wordpress/fil1', 
            '/ebooks/wordpress/fil2', 
            '/ebooks/wordpress/fil3']

excludes = [  '/data/archive/', '/data' , '/ebooks/'   ]

for location in locations:
  for exclude in excludes:
    if not location.startswith(exclude):
      print(location)
    break
```

RESULT:

```
/data/mybackup/data/fil1
/data/mybackup/data/fil2
/data/mybackup/data/fil3
/data/mybackup/song/fil1
/data/mybackup/song/fil2
/data/mybackup/song/fil3
/local/archive/data/fil2
/local/archive/data/fil3
/ebboks/wordpress/fil1
/ebooks/wordpress/fil2
/ebooks/wordpress/fil3
```

My result still have the file names starting with '/data'

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: `str.startswith` takes a tuple... If you make `excludes` a tuple instead of a list, you can do `if not location.startswith(excludes)` in one go and not have to worry about ordering/overlaps or the subloop

Comment: I think this is really just a logical error, not so much a python question. The inner loop over `excludes` will always only test against `excludes[0]` and `break`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.startswith` accepts a `tuple` of arguments to check against so you avoid an additional loop to check and concerns about ordering comparisons, so you can use:

```
exc = tuple(excludes)
# Or start with: excludes = ('/data/archive/', '/data' , '/ebooks/') instead
for location in locations:
    if not location.startswith(exc):
        print(location)
```

Which gives you:

```
/local/archive/data/fil2
/local/archive/data/fil3
/ebboks/wordpress/fil1
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort to solve this problem. Your solution really worked well.

Answer (score 3):

> Condition: do **not** print the file name if it starts with the **any** of the strings in
>   the excludes list.

With `all()` function:

```
for location in locations:
    if all(not location.startswith(e) for e in excludes):
        print(location)
```

The output:

```
/local/archive/data/fil2
/local/archive/data/fil3
/ebboks/wordpress/fil1
```

Answer (score 2):

For `location` is , let's say, `"/data/mybackup/data/fil1"` and `exclude` is `"/data/archive"`, the `location` variable doesn't start with `"/data/archive"`.

As you have a `"/data"` value in your `excludes` list, you don't need to put another path that starts with `"/data"`. So if you define `excludes = ["/data", "/ebooks"]` there will be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are checking against `/data/archive/` first; it is letting all entries which are not starting with `/data/archive/` essentially skipping the check for `/data`.

You can do this:

```
>>> excludes = tuple(excludes)
>>> filter(lambda x: not x.startswith(excludes), locations)
['/local/archive/data/fil2', '/local/archive/data/fil3', '/ebboks/wordpress/fil1']
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check all excludes before printing the location.

Try changing this:

```
for location in locations:
  for exclude in excludes:
    if not location.startswith(exclude):
      print(location)
    break
```

To:

```
def valid(location):
  for exclude in excludes:
    if location.startswith(exclude):
      return False
  return True

for location in locations:
  if valid(location):
    print(location)
```

Answer (score 0):

try list comprehensions:

```
>>> [location for location in locations \
if not location.startswith(tuple(excludes))]
```

output:

```
['/local/archive/data/fil2', '/local/archive/data/fil3', '/ebboks/wordpress/fil1']
```

or `filter` with lambdas if you prefer functional programming in answer of @mshsayem